# Cytoscape.js can't get initial positions with cy.nodes().forEach

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm new to Cytoscape.js and so far I really appreciate what it  does. My issue is the following : for my project I need to create a graph that can be modified by the user, and I need to have a reset button that would replace all elements as the user found them in the first place.

I use the cose-bilkent layout as I take my data with no position information.

Here is my js code.

```js
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  style: [{
    selector: 'node',
    style: {
      shape: 'roundrectangle',
      'background-color': 'red',
      label: 'data(id )'
    }
  }, ],
});

cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt) {
  var node = evt.target;
  console.log("tap", node.id(), node.position());
});

cy.add([{
    data: {
      id: 'a'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'b'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'c'
    }
  },

  {
    data: {
      id: 'ab',
      source: 'a',
      target: 'b'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'ac',
      source: 'a',
      target: 'c'
    }
  }
]);

cy.layout({
  name: 'cose-bilkent',
  avoidOverlap: true,
  avoidOverlapPadding: 10,
}).run();

cy.nodes().forEach(function(ele) {
  console.log("loop", ele.id(), ele.position());
});
```

When I look at the console after having clicked on a node, I see the following :

[node c in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLFmZ.jpg)

My question is : why when I click on the nodes, the object position is correct ({x: 30, y: 30}), whereas in the loop the object is {x:0, y:0} ?

EDIT : 
After Stephan's answer I changed my code to the following :

```
var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),

    style: [
        {
            selector: 'node',
            style: {
                shape: 'roundrectangle',
                'background-color': 'red',
                label: 'data(id )'
            }
        },
    ],
});

cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt) {
    var node = evt.target;
    console.log("tap", node.id(), node.position());
});

cy.add([
    { data: { id: 'a' } },
    { data: { id: 'b' } },
    { data: { id: 'c' } },

    {
        data: {
            id: 'ab',
            source: 'a',
            target: 'b'
        }
    },
    {
        data: {
            id: 'ac',
            source: 'a',
            target: 'c'
        }
    }
]);

cy.layout({
    name: 'cose-bilkent',
    avoidOverlap: true,
    avoidOverlapPadding: 10,
}).run();

setTimeout( function() {
    cy.nodes().forEach(function(ele){
        console.log("loop", ele.id(), ele.position());
    });
}, 2000);

// Not Working :
//    cy.ready( function() {
//        cy.nodes().forEach(function(ele){
//          console.log("loop", ele.id(), ele.position());
//        });
//    });
```

SOLUTION :

In the end I found a somewhat better solution : I  used the event 'layoutstop' in order to start the copy of positions at the right moment :

```
cy.on('layoutstop', function() {
    cy.nodes().forEach(function(ele){
        console.log("loop", ele.id(), ele.position().x, ele.position().y);
    });
});
```

However if you use this solution you have to know that it doesn't work with an exterior function (for some unknown reason). Thus the following won't work :

```
cy.on('layoutstop', copyPos());
function copyPos() {
  cy.nodes().forEach(function(ele){
    console.log("loop", ele.id(), ele.position().x, ele.position().y);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your function, it seems to work fine with me, the loop returns the model position (absolute position) of each node. The only thing that comes to my mind is that you call the function before the nodes actually loaded:

```
var cy = cytoscape({
  ...
  style: [...],
});

cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt) {
  var node = evt.target;
  console.log("tap", node.id(), node.position());
});

cy.add([...]);

                    // Wait for the eles to be added
cy.layout({...}).run();                // Call layout on eles

cy.ready(function () {                 // Wait for cytoscape to actually load and map eles
    cy.nodes().forEach(function(ele) { // Your function call inside
          console.log("loop", ele.id(), ele.position());
    });
});
```

Before cytoscape's layout is fully loaded, all nodes start at the position (0,0), which then is changed (async function). So that may be why your funciton does that...

Comment: thanks for the answer, that didn't work. however, with this idea in mind I set a timeout and it fixed my issue. Isn't there a better way to do this ?

Comment: setTimeout( function() {
    cy.nodes().forEach(function(ele){
      console.log("loop", ele.id(), ele.position());
    });
  }, 2000);

Comment: But it should work like that, your timeout function is not really the solution here, can you show your current code?

Comment: Like I said, the only thing causing the trouble is, that your position() is called before your graph is ready.

Comment: You can check, if the cy.ready() works properly, by going to the dev tools  and setting the breakpoints on the cy.ready(), if the function is called before your cy.layout().run() finished, then the error comes from that, otherwise it should work.  EDIT: wiered, that never happened to me, but i am glad it works now

Comment: EDIT : nevermind I changed my tests to better see the results and it doesn't work for him either. As for the breakpoint, the console displays the position long before anything appears on the web page, so the issue is as you said.

Comment: It doesn't work :(. if I put the cy.ready function above the cy.layout().run(), then the cy.ready() is never run.

Comment: EDIT : if I put the cy.ready function above the nodes and edges declarations,, then the cy.ready function is never run. If I place the cy.ready function between the nodes/edges declarations and the layout.run function, or after the layout.run  function then it is run, but before the graph appears

Comment: What are your imports? The graph may not appear on the screen, but it probably already exists. The .ready() function really should work properly, the error may be caused by a false import of cytoscape or a wrong init, but that doesnt seem to be the case...

Comment: cytoscape.js, and cytoscape-cose-bilkent.js

Comment: According to npm I have cytoscape@3.2.12 and cytoscape-cose-bilkent@4.0.0